# How can a component obtain a value synchronously from its parent?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, synchronous

Consider the following Ember component which is using [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['ui', 'mini', 'modal'],
  didInsertElement() {
    this.$().modal({
      onApprove: () => {
        let promise = // obtain promise from parent... somehow
        promise.then(() => {
          this.$().modal('hide');
        });
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The modal dialog is initialized as soon as the element is accessible. The `onApprove` option specifies a callback to be invoked when the user clicks "OK" in the dialog. The component's parent supplies an [`Ember.RSVP.Promise`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/RSVP.Promise), which when resolved, closes the dialog.

Herein lies the problem — how do I obtain the promise from the parent? I considered the following possibilities:

- The parent could supply an action to be invoked:

  ```
  {{modal-dialog action='getPromise'}}
  ```

  However, actions cannot return values, so although the component could invoke the action, it could not use it to obtain the promise.
- The parent could supply the promise as a bound property:

  ```
  {{modal-dialog promise=promise}}
  ```

  The problem with this approach is that `didInsertElement()` cannot obtain the promise itself since the component must wait for the `promise` property to mutate.

Is there a way for a component to ask the parent for a value in a synchronous manner?

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain the promise from the parent"?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the parent creates the promise in response to the modal's OK button being clicked and the component then needs access to the promise in order to close itself when the promise resolves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

closure action will return the value so you can return the Promise in closure action.

```
{{modal-dialog getPromise=(action 'getPromise'}}
```

if getPromise method is returning the promise then you can get it like this `let promise = this.get('getPromise')()`